# Show Dependencies manager In Solution Explorer for VS2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, bower

In Visual Studio 2015, when you create a new Web Application template using the starter web template, you get an item in solution explorer called "Dependencies" which helps you manage your bower/npm packages.  However, if you create a new Web Application using MVC, this item is missing.  How would you add it? I noticed the new template uses .xproj as the extension, while the original uses .csproj.

Shows Dependencies node:

[image]

Missing Dependencies node even with bower/package.json files present:

[image]

Comment: Hey there, I don't suppose you managed to get to the bottom of this at all?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I found a workaround, however.  Here are the steps:
1) Add "grunt-bower-task": "0.4.0", to your devDependencies in package.json
2) In gruntfile.js add a task as follows:
        bower: {
            install: {
                options: {
                    targetDir: "bower_components",
                    layout: "byComponent"
                }
            }
        }
3) Enable the "Task Runner Explorer" tab from Visual Studio 2015, to run bower from within VS.

Comment: Created an issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1780

Comment: Well, that's because as you stated, one of them is xproj and another one is csproj. They are interpreted differently by VS. I don't think this'll ever get implemented..